# I'm wanting a button to navigate to a form but it isn't showing the form when I click the button

Tags: powerapps, power-platform

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix my problem of when I click on a button that it will navigate to my form1 with the data cards in the form?

1. [Image - edit form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4JiS.png)
2. [Inspection form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nK6FO.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to navigate to the form in Screen 2 from Screen 1, if that is the case, in the OnSelect property of Button,try

```
    Navigate(Screen2);
```